# How to combine multiple word documents while preserving headers

Tags: microsoft-word, automation

My question is similar [asadim's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/aad6791b-22c4-4b98-894d-e3ebe11076d1) from October 2010, "I have several Word files that I want to merge into a single doc file. Some of these docs have header/footer while some don't. Also the headers/footers are not identical across all files. Is there a way to merge these into a single doc while preserving the headers/footers?"

The answer from that forum is "use the Master Document feature"; this is nice, but I would like to automate the process a little further.  Ideally, I envision an Automator workflow (on Mac OS X), so that I can just drag and drop the files to be combined from Finder. However, if I can get it as a command-line utility, that might work as well. (Something along the lines of: `combine_docs.sh source1.doc source2.doc source3.doc destination.doc`)

Thanks!